An EmailSendDefinition must have an audience to be sent
I'm attempting to use the SFMC SOAP API to send a marketing/commercial email. All steps should be done programatically. I'm starting with one email for now but eventually this will be a bulk email.
I try to perform the send, but I get an error `An EmailSendDefinition must have an audience to be sent. I'm guessing this means I need to associate subscribers to the send definition? I see how to create subscriber lists and add them to the list.
However, I've looked at the docs for Email Send Definition and don't see how to associate subscribers to it. I see a section that does mention "audience" using Filters, but it's not clear how that works.
Perform action request body:
<PerformRequestMsg
    xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options/>
    <Action>start</Action>
    <Definitions>
        <Definition xsi:type="ns1:EmailSendDefinition"
            xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <CustomerKey>ATTN_20</CustomerKey>
        </Definition>
    </Definitions>
</PerformRequestMsg>

Perform action response error:
....
<StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
<StatusMessage>An EmailSendDefinition must have an audience to be sent.
  ClientID: ....
  EmailSendDefinitionID: ....
  EmailSendDefinition Name: ATTN_20
  CustomerKey: ATTN_20</StatusMessage>
<ErrorCode>105</ErrorCode>
....

Request to create send definition:
<CreateRequest
    xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options/>
    <Objects xsi:type="ns1:EmailSendDefinition"
        xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <CustomerKey>ATTN_20</CustomerKey>
        <Name>ATTN_20</Name>
        <SendClassification>
            <CustomerKey>ATTN_TEST_2</CustomerKey>
        </SendClassification>
        <DeliveryProfile>ATTN_CAMPAIGN</DeliveryProfile>
        <Email>
            <CustomerKey>ATTN_13</CustomerKey>
        </Email>
        <IsMultipart>false</IsMultipart>
    </Objects>
</CreateRequest>


SFMC SOAP API to send a marketing/commercial email - it sounds like you're doing more than that. Typical approach is to set up things manually in MC, then use APIs to send. If you're trying to do everything via APIs, please edit your question and explain what you're trying to accomplish.

@identigral It might be knowledge blindspots on my end, but AFAIK you have to setup a send definition prior performing a send for marketing/commercial email? I updated the question a bit but it's more or less the same question: how to use SFMC SOAP API to send commercial/marketing email?

There are many options. One is to kick off a journey via API - follow the example in Journey Builder section of https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-apis/use-rest-api-across-marketing-cloud

You need to add the SendDefinitionList attributes in the createrequest object
                <SendDefinitionList>
                    <CustomerKey>{{externalkey of dataextension}}</CustomerKey>
                    <DataSourceTypeID>CustomObject</DataSourceTypeID>
                </SendDefinitionList>

Complete object request
      <Objects xsi:type="EmailSendDefinition">
            <Client>
                <ID>{{MID}}</ID>
            </Client>
            <CustomerKey>{{externalkey}}</CustomerKey>
            <Name>{{Name}}</Name>
            <Description>{{Description}}</Description>
            <SendClassification>
                <CustomerKey>{{Commercial/Transactional}}</CustomerKey>
            </SendClassification>
            <SendDefinitionList>
                <CustomerKey>{{externalkey of dataextension}}</CustomerKey>
                <DataSourceTypeID>CustomObject</DataSourceTypeID>
            </SendDefinitionList>
            <Email>
                <ID>{{emiailID}}</ID>
            </Email>
        </Objects>

